# Application crashes(bad_alloc) because task_group leaks reserved memory

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, memory-management, concurrency

EDIT: this was originally thought to be a fragmentation problem, here is a more precise statement of the problem.

I have this perfectly working code:

```
while(true)
{
    Job job = provider.NextJob();
    if (job.get() == NULL)
    {
        Result jobResult = job.Run();
        provider.ProcessJobResult(jobResult);       
    }
    else
    break;
}
```

I reimplement it: (originally there were several threads, but a single thread still manifests the problem)

```
JobProvider provider;
Concurrency::task_group taskGroup;

std::function<void ()> processingJob = [&provider, &taskGroup, &processingJob]
{
    Job job = provider.NextJob();
    if (job.get() == NULL)
    {
        Result jobResult = job.Run();
        provider.ProcessJobResult(jobResult);
        taskGroup.run(jobCode);
    }
};

taskGroup.run(jobCode);
taskGroup.wait();
```

This code crashes due to no memory after a while.
To analyse memory space I used:

1. function `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` in `crtdbg.h` - which shows there are no leaks if the amount of jobs is small enough to let the application complete and exit.
2. this profiler: http://hashpling.org/asm/
   This is what the profiler shows:
   [image: Profiler output]

Red means committed, Yellow reserved and Green, which was entirely consumed, means free.
Threads that `taskGroup` creates don't clean reserved memory. Can anyone say why?

Comment: Do you release the memory after each image? This sounds more like a memory leak than fragmentation at first glance.

Comment: Yes I do, images are large enough to be seen as red stripes and this picture was taken after processing over 2GB of images. It looks like a lot of small objects are living among the reserved yellow area. The red mass in the end shifted from left to right with time.

Comment: It sounds like small chunks of memory may be getting leaked. If everything is cleaned up after each image fragmentation shouldn't be a problem. If you have access to Purify or the ability to compile on Linux and use valgrind that's probably your best bet here.

Comment: Not everything is cleaned up. Processing results (small objects) are accumulated. I'm am afraid I don't have neither options.

Comment: Use the debugger to view the reserved regions, see what they belong to. Maybe they are reserved for stacks of threads that you leaked? Or reserved for heap blocks that you leaked?

Comment: I'm sure it's not the threads. Is the option of fragmentation likely?

Comment: @Raymond Chen, I edited everything, please see again. The problem might be what you suggested but I'm not sure why.

Comment: There is not enough information to diagnose the problem. `JobProvider` is not a standard C++ class, so who knows what it does or whether it is leaking. You could use the debugger to view the reserved regions and see who they belong to.

Comment: @Raymond Chen - I forgot to mention, using crtdbg.h I verified that there are no leaks if I limit the amount of time the code runs (give it less jobs) so that it completes and exits. So the fault seems to be on `task_group`'s side

Comment: I'll say it a third time: Use the debugger to view the reserved regions and see who they belong to.